# Arrayformula not working for Google Spreadsheet settings having locale other than US

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, formula, locale, array-formulas

I have created a Google spreadsheet with `Locale` set to `Brazil` and `Timezone` set to `(GMT-03:00) Sau Paulo` that has a `Date column` having dates in their regional format like `01-jan.-2021, 23-fev.-2021` etc.

I have created a `Month` column next to this Date column and trying to populate the months using Arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F2:F),MONTH(F2:F),))
```

It doesn't seem to work if i use `IF` or `LEN` in the Arrayformula function, however, seems to work if i simply do this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH(F2:F))
```

which obviously fills down all rows including blank date cells and adds more rows.

Another thing i noted is, if i change the Spreadsheet settings to `Locale : United States` & `Timezone : Eastern Time (GMT-04:00)`, the Arrayformula with both the `IF` & `LEN` functions seems to work! However, it doesn't work for the above region.

If anyone has an alternative solution to make it work, please do share here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Google Spreadsheet, the arguments in any given function are separated either by a decimal point OR a decimal comma. The applicable separator depends on the spreadsheet locale (File, Spreadsheet settings, Locale) and the [decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) used by that country

- If the locale is a country that uses a decimal point (`.`) as a decimal separator, then function arguments are typically separated by use a comma (`,`).
- If the locale is a country that uses a decimal comma (`,`) as a decimal separator, then function arguments are typically separated by use a semi-colon (`;`).

---

Brazil uses a decimal comma, so Google Sheet arguments are separated by a semi-colon.

- `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F2:F),MONTH(F2:F),))`: **FAIL**
- `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F2:F);MONTH(F2:F);))`: **SUCCESS**

---

United States uses a decimal point), so Google Sheets should be separated by a comma.

- `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F2:F),MONTH(F2:F),))`: **SUCCESS**
- `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F2:F),MONTH(F2:F),))`: **FAIL**

The snapshots below are taken from two spreadsheets (#1 locale=Brazil, #2 Locale=USA) and demonstrate the application of a comma or a semi-colon as a argument separator.

---

**Brazil**

[image: Brazil]

---

**USA**

[image: USA]

Answer (score 0):

There is also situation where working with arrays using curly brackets {...} **requires using both ; or , in english**. semicolon is used to make one dimensional array and coma is used to make more columns of array.

In that case you you need to **use backslash** instead of coma in other Locales. (using Slovakia locale in my example)

- one dimension array US `={A1:A10; C1:C10}`
- multi-dimesion array US `={A1:A10, C1:C10}`
- one dimension array SK `={A1:A10, C1:C10}`
- multi-dimension array SK `={A1:A10\ C1:C10}`